# cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, recv

hey can someone help me with some socket issues
here is the code https://github.com/websitdev/discordBridge/blob/master/main.py when i run this file i get

```py
127.0.0.1
65432
server is running!
discord end is running!
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/arydev/github/discordBridge/net.py", line 55, in net
    m=recv_msg(s)
  File "/home/arydev/github/discordBridge/net.py", line 30, in recv_msg
    reqest=server.recv(50)
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/arydev/github/discordBridge/discord_bot/discord_bot.py", line 57, in discord_bot
    type_,group,msg=recv_msg()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem in order for us to spot the bug easily?

Comment: @Léonard this is i can give you my config file if you want